# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to0}(f(x)g(x)-g(x))$, given $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$, $\lim_{x\to0}g(x)$, $g(7)$, and $f(-4)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, solution-verification

I tried solving this and I am not sure if my solution and answer is right.

> Given: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x)=7,\lim_{x\rightarrow0}g(x)=-4,g(7)=3\text{ and } f(-4) = 2$$
> Determine: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\left(f(x)g(x)-g(x)\right)$$

Here's my solution so far:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \left(f(x)g(x)-g(x)\right) &= \left(\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x)\right)\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow0}g(x)\right) -\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow0}g(x)\right) \\
&= 7(-4)-(-4)\\
&= - 24.
\end{align*}

Is this correct?

Comment: Seems correct to me!

Comment: Your answer and approach is correct. The values of those functions were given to misguide/confuse reader. All that matters is the limit of $f, g$.